# find max of factor and index that max in r

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

This should be incredibly simple, but I'm not managing to figure it out.  I want to get max value per group, which I do as follows.

```
ddply(dd,~group,summarise,max=max(value))
```

But in addition to returning the value and group, I want to return value, group, and another column, date, indexed below (obviously doesn't work).  How do I do it? Thanks.

```
ddply(dd,~group,summarise,max=max(value))['date']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after the date that corresponds to the row(s) with the max values, try `subset` to get the row of the max along with `select` to get the columns you're after.

```
# reproducible example using `iris`

# your original
ddply(iris, ~Species, summarise, max=max(Sepal.Length))
#      Species max
# 1     setosa 5.8
# 2 versicolor 7.0
# 3  virginica 7.9


# now we want to get the Sepal.Width that corresponds to max sepal.length too.
ddply(iris, ~Species, subset, Sepal.Length==max(Sepal.Length),
      select=c('Species', 'Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width'))
#      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 1     setosa          5.8         4.0
# 2 versicolor          7.0         3.2
# 3  virginica          7.9         3.8
```

(Or instead of using `select` in the `subset` call, just use `[, c('columns', 'I', 'want')]` after the `ddply`). If there are multiple rows for the same species that attain the maximum, this will return all of them.

You can use `summarise` to do it too, just add your `date` definition in the call, but it's a little less efficient (calculating the max twice):

```
ddply(iris, ~Species, summarise,
      max=max(Sepal.Length),
      width=Sepal.Width[which.max(Sepal.Length)])
```

This will only return one row per species, and if there are multiple flowers with the maximum sepal length for their species, only the first is returned (`which.max` returns the first of the matching indices).

Comment: worked perfectly.  thank you for the multiple solutions.

For future reference, this is what I ended up opting for. 
ddply(dd, ~group, subset, value==max(value),
      select=c('date2', 'value'))

Answer (score 1):

If we are using `data.table` (using `iris` dataset), we convert the data.frame to data.table, grouped by the grouping variable ('Species'), we get the index of the `max` value of one variable ('Sepal.Length') and use that to subset the columns that are indicated in the .SDcols.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(iris)
dt[, .SD[which.max(Sepal.Length)]  , by = Species, 
                 .SDcols= c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')]
```